# What did I feel testing a car battery?

Tags: batteries

Was trying to test the voltage of my car battery but accidently had the multimeter set up for Amps (was using it for an old project and forgot to switch cables/turn the dial).

Turned my multimeter on. Connected the terminal to my car battery to test for a flat and while holding the multimeter probes thought i felt something travel through my fingers. No pain or anything. Just a very odd sensation.

It's a 12V battery. I know (from the sparks and 30 seconds on google) they pack a LOT of current but surely there isn't enough voltage to shock me through the (a) plastic handles of the multimeter, and (b) my skin.

So what did I feel? The multimeter is only rated for 10A. Any chance it could have 'failed dangerously' when I accidently overloaded it? Or was the sensation in the probes just the sudden surge of current inducing some sort of force in the wire?

Thanks for you help. Panicking a bit.

Comment: Thanks in advance. Used to breadboards / arduino type stuff so understand the basics -I just don't usually mess about with anything with that much current!!

Comment: Most likely the wires got hot.  Possibly blew the fuse in the meter - you might have felt the "pop" when it went out.

Comment: What you felt was momentary? If so, could be the inductive kick-back pulse when your multimeter blew open (or you jerked the connection open-circuit).

Comment: I seriously don't think you felt anything except surprise and fear. 12v can't hurt you through your fingers, and definitely can't through the plastic multimeter lead handles.

Comment: Even the inductive kick will no way go through the multimeter handles, and the fuse will blow long before the wires get noticeably hot, unless you've replaced it with a lump of metal...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A multimeter in ampmeter mode is basically a short.

If you're lucky, the multimeter has a fuse that instantly burned when you connected the battery – a charged, a shorted car battery can easily source > 80 A, and that just vaporizes a lot of on-board conductor traces.

So, what you might have been feeling is

1. the electromotive force due to wires with very high currents running in opposite direction being very close
2. the thermal reaction of measurement leads most definitely not speced for shorting car batteries (compare your multimeter leads to car jumper wires. Assume that at least 70% of your lead's diameter is isolation.)
3. something in your multimeter violently exploding and that mechanical shock being sent down the wires.
4. your nervous system's shock response to seeing sparks and hearing something pop.
5. Back-EMF: a fuse blowing has very high derivative of current over time, which means that the very little inductance of your wires might have caused a very high voltage for very shortly, think a couple kV. That might actually have shot through your isolation, but honestly, the resulting current would most likely have been low enough to not pose a danger

Comment: Thank you. Understand everything you just said. I think it was just a bit of a panic attack. I know its Amps that are dangerous and seeing the sparks made me have a bit of a (no pun intended) meltdown!! Calmed down a bit now. The Ammeter mode is definitely fried. (5) worries me a bit. The plastic is insulating, but it's not super thick. Presumably it blew at 10A. Any ideas what sort of current mightve travelled through me?

Comment: Appreciate V=IR but have no idea the resistance of the probes... or my (dry) skin. Presumably comfortably onto the mili-ohms!?

Comment: My students regularly measure voltages by ammeter in the lab... and I regularly replace fuses:) Unfortunately, at 20 mA range the SMD shunt resistor manages to burn out before the 0.5 A fuse. So most of the multimeters in the laboratory do not function at this range...

Comment: @JimT:  Your skin resistance is normally in the tens of thousands of ohms.  If your skin resistance were in the milliohms (thousandsths of an ohm) then you would "look" like a short circuit to all batteries - touching the poles of a battery would cause sparks.  Dry skin normally has a resistance high enough that no noticeable current will flow through if you stay below about 50V.

Comment: sorry meant to say Mega*! Sorry - on site and have cold fingers. I figured the protection of the multimeter was probabpy in the region of megaohms so even if the back emf peaked at at KV's presumably i'm still getting a shock comfortably in the microamps range. Anyway - thank you! appreciate it was mostly panic on my part

Comment: Right. rationalizing that the protection was in the mega-ohms, plus that the duration of the back EMF was likely to be instantaneous, i.e. very short. Marcus, unless you think I've got an order of magnitude wrong and the current mightve exceeded a mili-amp, or my assessment re: the duration is wrong, i am content if someone wants to close this. Thank you for the answers, appreciate it, has put my mind at rest.

Comment: 6. The ghost of Thomas Edison screaming and manically laughing, "DC... DC... DC...!"

Comment: @JimT Re: "any idea of the current that travelled through me": no, not at all. The *energy* of that pulse you might have experienced was however most certainly low. As said, don't worry. You're fine, right? Unless you exhibit symptoms of cardiac arrhythmia now that you didn't before, there's little reason to assume damage has been taken. However, like always: when it comes to health, strangers on the internet don't matter. Doctors do. But honestly, as a physician, my opening question would be: do you feel worse than before? and if that's not the case, you don't have damage.

Comment: @MarcusMüller  You can have wounds that go silent in examination or sensation that can be life threatening later. But Physician's are not responsible for healing you, you are. They are only responsible for nearly or accidentally killing you.

Comment: @MarcusMüller “>80A” ... a direct short across a battery can exceed 1000A and I have seen steel bar glow red - not suggesting you try that though - batteries can explode.. also a battery can make a good power source to stick weld.. :)

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 exactly; a physician being told you did something that has a realistic chance of causing latent injuries will have you examined; a physician being told you felt a tingle and then nothing bad happened will not.

Answer (score 2):

Who hasn't done this before and burnt out the fuse?

When batteries are new they are rated for the reduced ability at freezing temperatures to supply current to a starter motor.  The battery struggles to sustain that current and it's voltage is allowed to drop by 5V from 12.5V to achieve it's maximum CCA rating.  This is the worst case when the engine is seized up cold and the start motor stalls or barely turns it over but normally the car only needs a small fraction of this in warm weather to get started.

Let's look at some reasonable values say of CCA = 850 Amps which is **5V/850=0.006 Ohms**.  That power is 7.5V*850A= 6,375 Watts or 6 kilowatts.

Now let's look at [a 10A fuse](https://www.digikey.ca/product-detail/en/bel-fuse-inc/5HT-10-R/507-1217-ND/1008989) specs. DC Cold Resistance     0.007 Ohms 
 [image]

Now imagine that fuse and the wire is going to get pretty hot in an explosive manner and may not reach 6 kilowatts in a tiny space due to probe tip resistance but enough to melt the fuse and cause big sparks.

The sparks are not from making the initial contact but actually from bouncing and breaking contact. What happens next is a product of ionization and RF low impedance resonant circuit with wire inductance and stray capacitance. During that moment of high current being released, the physics of inductance is like inertia of current and it creates an extremely high voltage across the gap about 2 kV +/-1 per mm of gap. It takes a short time to ionize and heat up the air in an arc which then collapse the high voltage across the arc then the current resonates with a decaying arc until you pull it away far enough that the arc resistance is too high to sustain.  Now this generates RF energy in a loop around the wire and the smaller the loop the higher the frequency and energy of this frequency to be absorbed into your body.  Because the arc was intermittent the current was highly modulated in amplitude and also the voltage.  This means it was acting with more power than the original  Morse Code Telegraph machines made by Seimens across Europe. But you were right next to the high
power RF.

Current by the way is defined as the rate of change of charges Q.  (I=dQ/dt)

So what you should have felt is the modulation of the arc energizing your body and dielectric in your hair with some sensations perhaps reaching the activation threshold some axons in your feeling sensors.  This requires a pretty high Magnetic Field of about 1 to 2 Tesla's but was so short in time duration , that it could be easy to ignore yet easy to feel some sensations without pain.

In Slovenia, there is a  company that produces these 2 to 4 Tesla pulses for 10ms 300Hz ringing at 30ish Hz rep rate (Shumman resonance)  with magnetic coils like an old magnetic tape degausser but at much higher levels required for therapy of healing nerve damage and exciting muscles without pain like electro-stim. Because this is extremely low frequency, it takes a lot of current to stimulate nerve conductors called axons.  The machine is called the Tesla Stym. I wish I had one for my Neuropathy. [image]Maybe someone can order it for me and put it on my visa as they don't/can't sell to North America AFAIK.

H[ere is a simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000009999999999999999%206.450009306485578%2059%20120%2050%0Ag%20224%20176%20224%20192%200%0AR%20224%20160%20192%20160%204%205%204%2012%200%200%200.01%0Aw%20272%20336%20320%20336%200%0Ag%20320%20336%20320%20368%200%0Aw%20352%20224%20384%20224%202%0Aw%20320%20336%20384%20336%201%0Ac%20320%20336%20320%20224%200%202.5e-11%20-552.9764685738955%0A187%20384%20256%20384%20336%200%201%201000000000%201000%200.001%0Av%20272%20336%20272%20224%200%200%2040%2012.5%200%200%200.5%0Al%20272%20224%20320%20224%200%200.000009999999999999999%20-0.47034282741708466%0A178%20272%20128%20336%20128%200%201%200.2%201.707740790308264e-57%200.01%201000000%200.02%20200%0Aw%20272%20160%20224%20160%200%0Aw%20272%20176%20224%20176%200%0Ag%20272%20128%20272%20144%200%0Aw%20336%20144%20336%20224%203%0Aw%20320%20224%20336%20224%200%0Aw%20352%20224%20336%20224%202%0A403%20416%20112%20800%20192%200%2014_64_0_12546_2404.7487478645007_0.0001_0_2_14_3%0A403%20416%20272%20800%20464%200%207_64_0_12545_0.0001_95.22697626593212_0_2_7_3%0A181%20384%20224%20384%20256%200%20605.3704195406902%2060%20120%200.04%200.04%0A403%20416%200%20800%2080%200%201_64_0_4354_20_0.1_0_2_1_3%0A) using a relay to pulse a short circuit with a 1mm gap and the arc is across the relay contacts (destructive test).  You can do this if you are safe.

Comment: Is the frequency / intensity of any of this RF likely to be harmful? i.e. presumably this was all below infrared i.e. radiowaves so the onlyrisk would be dialectric heating? in any case, would there be enough of it to be harmful?

Comment: The arc is about 5000'C but the RF is too short duration to cause any heat rise in eyes that over a long period can cause cataracts. That's why they position Cell towers very very carefully.

Comment: Ok - thank you. I was going to say - I didnt feel particularly  like I 'cooked' myself. In any case - thought microwave cooking relied on a resonant cavity to generate the waves rather than a bit of cabling. Think I'm going to have a cup of tea and relax! Crazy to think, looking back, a simple multimeter probe could act as an inductor to create a 2T magnetic field, albeit for a fleeting moment. Thank you. Jim.

Comment: I've been trying to create these but it's not easy to sustain this power without cooking FETs and coil wires.  The arc also breaks the sound barrier to make the pop sound.